# Aligning an image to the right without text wrapping around it in HTML

Tags: html

Consider this being slipped into some HTML file right after a `<body>` tag and before some text:

```
<div style="width:100%; height=320pix; background-color:black">
<img src="logo.jpg">
</div>
```

For me, this creates a black "banner" at the top of the browser page, with the logo image (320pix high) aligned to the left. How can I move it to the right and leave the text exactly as is? I would like to know the simplest addition to this code to achieve that. When I specify `style="float:right"` in the `<img ...>` tag line, the text that follows wraps around it, destroying the banner effect.

However... if I transfer the same elements into a `<style>...</style>` block within the HTML, and include an `img{float:right;}` everything works fine. I just do not understand why the floating behaviour should be different between the two approaches. My head is about to explode...

A possible lead - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738964/css-image-on-right-side-of-page-with-text-not-wrapping-around-it) indicates that it should be simple, but when I try precisely the code given, it still does not work. Could it be a !DOCTYPE or similar issue? I am using Firefox 15.0.1 as my browser.

Comment: `320pix` is invalid. It should be `320px`

Comment: Yes - a typo :-). I have subsequently confirmed that inserting `style="float:right"` displays as I'd like it on IE8, but not on Google Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the DIV containing the image a relative position. This will allow you to position the image absolutely within it.

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:320px; background-color:black">

    <img src="logo.jpg" style="position:absolute; right:0px;">

</div>
```

Adjust the 'right' to position the image to your liking.

Comment: This failed to work for me on Firefox 15.0.1 - does it work for you?

Comment: Works in Firefox 10.0.2. Not tested on 15.0.1, but I can't understand why it wouldn't, it's a fairly standard method of positioning. Is there any reason for choosing inline style?

Comment: It's a temporary edit going into dozens of files... and then out of them later. The more local I can make the changes, the better.

Comment: My apologies - I typed in the extra positioning, rather than cutting and pasting the whole lot. I must have edited out the `height:320px` in the div line because it worked fine when I retried.